# for three times / on my way stumbling towards the bus

Tags: phrases, expressions

In the following sentence:

I paused three times on my way stumbling towards the bus.

Is it okay if I omit the “for” in “for three times” like I did? Which one is more common, “three times” or “for three times”?

Also, did I use “stumbling” correctly in this sentence? I want to express that I was stumbling as I walked to the bus...

Any help appreciated! Thank you! (:

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is nearly perfect the way you wrote it.

I would add a comma  "I paused three times on my way, stumbling towards the bus."